# How to assign multiple variables without repeating a clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have around 10 variables which all need to be populated during my select statement.

It's all driven by a language code, if 'english' set all variables to english, otherwise set to native language.

The issue I'm having is alot of repeat code, I'm wondering what's the best approach to populate multiple variables within a CASE.

My current code

```
DECLARE
@x nvarchar(200),
@y nvarchar(200),
@z nvarchar(200)

SELECT
    @x = CASE WHEN @language like '%english%'
            THEN                                        
                T.washroom_English
            ELSE                                            
                T.washroom
        END,
    @y = CASE WHEN @language like '%english%'
            THEN                                        
                T.bed_English
            ELSE                                            
                T.bed
        END,
    @z = CASE WHEN @language like '%english%'
            THEN                                        
                T.kitchen_English
            ELSE                                            
                T.kithen
        END
FROM house as T
```

Comment: I would say that the best way to do it is to try to denormalize data: have 1 record for each language and use this language in a query, or extract string values to a separate entity which is worse in terms of query performance. Imagine after a year someone comes to you and says "our project is extending and now we need to support 15 other languages", and imagine how fun it would be to implement it this way :)

Comment: @Phoenix, its not clear why you want each column value in a variable; what are you doing with the vars?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query wich will generate rows by language (english or not english) according to your @language variable.
The `UNION ALL` result will have the columns name same as the upper query.

Then you can assign your variables with a static column name from the subquery.

```
  SELECT @x = washroom
       , @y = bed
       , @z = kitchen
FROM   ( SELECT T.washroom
              , T.bed
              , T.kitchen
         FROM   house AS T
         WHERE  @language NOT LIKE '%english%'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT T.washroom_English
              , T.bed_English
              , T.kitchen_English
         FROM   house AS T
         WHERE  @language LIKE '%english%' 
       ) data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my little trick

```
DECLARE @English NVARCHAR(10) = '_English'
DECLARE @Fields NVARCHAR(500) = 'washroom,bed,kithen,'
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50) = 'house'
DECLARE @ColumnValue NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Index INT
DECLARE @SelectString NVARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT ' 
 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @Fields) > 0
 BEGIN
    SELECT @Index  = CHARINDEX(',', @Fields)  
    SELECT @ColumnValue = SUBSTRING(@Fields, 1, @Index-1)
    SET @SelectString = @SelectString + '''' + @ColumnValue + @English +'''As ' + @ColumnValue + ', '
    SELECT @Fields = SUBSTRING(@Fields, @Index + 1, LEN(@Fields) - @Index)
 END
SELECT @SelectString = SUBSTRING(@SelectString,0, LEN(@SelectString)) + ' From ' + @TableName
SELECT @SelectString  
EXEc sp_sqlexec @SelectString
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understood you correctly, but my proposition is:

```
DECLARE
@x nvarchar(200),
@y nvarchar(200),
@z nvarchar(200)

IF @language like '%english%'
    SELECT @x = T.washroom_English, @y = T.bed_English, @z = T.kitchen_English FROM house as T
ELSE
    SELECT @x = T.washroom, @y = T.bed, @z = T.kitchen FROM house as T
```